# ghc-modi and cabal version

Tags: haskell, intellij-idea, cabal, ghc-mod

(Haskell newbie here)

I'm trying to configure HaskForce plugin into IntelliJ IDEA, configured "ghc-mod" with "legacy-interactive" in "GHC Modi" `Flags`. The root problem seems to be related to cabal version, although when I try autocompleting on any Haskell symbol, I get this:

```
ghc-modi error
           Unable to parse problems from ghc-modi: cabal-helper-wrapper.exe: ghc: readCreateProcess: does not exist (No such file or directory)

           ghc-mod: readCreateProcess: C:\ACME\projects\htest\.cabal-sandbox\cabal-helper-0.5.3.0-553kah86RQN6BuDX6XLBiX\cabal-helper-wrapper.exe "C:\\ACME\\projects\\htest" "C:\\ACME\\projects\\htest\\dist" (exit 1): failed
```

When I run this last command (`C:\ACME\projects\htest\.cabal-sandbox\cabal-helper-0.5.3.0-553kah86RQN6BuDX6XLBiX\cabal-helper-wrapper.exe "C:\\ACME\\projects\\htest" "C:\\ACME\\projects\\htest\\dist"`), it tries to install cabal 1.18:

```
cabal-helper-wrapper.exe: Installing Cabal version 1.18.1.3 failed.
```

I already have cabal, of version 1.22 (installed via Haskell Platform v7.10.2-a, released recently in August).

Is there any way to work around this issue (i.e. still use `ghc-mod` / `ghc-modi`)?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?  Have you submitted this on the HaskForce and/or ghc-mod issue trackers?

Comment: @pyrospade: Carry Robbins has just released a new version of haskforce that is supposed to work with ghc-mod 5.4. I have to test it.

Comment: Here's a twist...I *am* Cary.  It seems that your error is related to the installation of ghc-mod.  You could, alternatively, build ghc-mod from source using stack or install it in a cabal sandbox.

Comment: @pyrospade: it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated Haskforce plugin (0.3-beta24) seems to work correctly with following ghc-mod:

```
ghc-mod version 5.4.0.0 compiled by GHC 7.10.2
```